# How to display code snippets in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex

Assume we have a source code in C++ like so:

```
void dfs(int p){
    if(o[p]) return;
    o[p]=1;
    c[p] = t++;
    for(int i=0; i<s[p].size(); ++i){
        dfs(s[p][i]);
    }
}
```

How do we properly display this source code in plain TeX?

The solution should keep all spaces, have all symbols, and use fixed width font.

Comment: You probably want to just use `eplain`. It has support for a bunch of things you might want, including a `\verbatim`.

Comment: @TH. This is unfortunately not possible since I cannot change neither environment nor the command which compiles the document. However if I had a choice, the **OPmac** (as pointed by wipet's answer) version seems as a good one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
\def\verbatim{%
  \begingroup
    \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }%
    \dospecials
    \obeylines
    \obeyspaces
    \tt
    \verbatimaux
}
\begingroup
\catcode`\|=0 %
\catcode`\\=12 %
|gdef|verbatimaux#1\endverbatim{#1|endverbatim}%
|endgroup
\def\endverbatim{\endgroup}
{\obeyspaces\gdef {\ }}% Omit this for 'explicit' spaces

\verbatim
void dfs(int p){
    if(o[p]) return;
    o[p]=1;
    c[p] = t++;
    for(int i=0; i<s[p].size(); ++i){
        dfs(s[p][i]);
    }
}
\endverbatim

\bye
```

should do you: a simplified version of LaTeX's `verbatim` environment. Also see Appendix E of *The TeXbook* (page 421), which described how Knuth did this for the book itself. (He requires every line is marked up using `|` ... `|`.)

Answer (score 9):

A version that breaks ligatures and obeys blank lines:

```
\def\verbatim{%
  \begingroup
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }%
  \dospecials
  \otherspecial\ {\ }%
  \otherspecial\-{-\kern0pt }%
  \otherspecial\`{\lq\kern0pt }%
  \otherspecial\'{\rq\kern0pt }%
  \otherspecial\^^M{\endgraf\ifblankline\vskip\baselineskip\fi\blanklinetrue}%
  \parindent0pt\medskip
  \everypar{\blanklinefalse}
  \tt\verbatimaux
}
\newif\ifblankline
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1
\catcode`\|=0 %
\catcode`\\=12 %
|gdef|verbatimaux#1\endverbatim#2{#1|endgroup|par|medskip}%
|endgroup%
\def\otherspecial#1#2{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text.
Some text some text some text some text some text some text.
Some text some text some text some text some text some text.

\verbatim
void dfs(int p){
    if(o[p]) return;
    o[p]=1;
    c[p] = t++;
    for(int i=0; i<s[p].size(); ++i){
        dfs(s[p][i]);
    }
}

-- --- `` '' `? `!
\endverbatim

Some text some text some text some text some text some text.
Some text some text some text some text some text some text.
Some text some text some text some text some text some text.

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When opmac is used then `\begtt`...`\endtt` environment is ready to use:

```
\input opmac

aha

\begtt
void dfs(int p){
    if(o[p]) return;
    o[p]=1;
    c[p] = t++;
    for(int i=0; i<s[p].size(); ++i){
        dfs(s[p][i]);
    }
}

// -- --- `` '' `? `!
\endtt

\bye
```

Moreover, you can copy the code from [this Opmac trick](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#hisyntax) and you can add
`\hisyntax{C}` before `\begtt` and you get the following result:

[image: ccode hisyntax]

Comment: In `opmac` you define `\setverb` with ``\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}`` inside; wouldn't it be safer to add a space after the `12` as is usual?

Comment: @Manuel The `\setverb` macro includes definition of the `\do` followed by its usage: `\dospecials` followed by `\catcode...`. So, the last `\do` expands to `\catcode`~=12\catcode...`. The missing space is irrelevant in this case, because `\catcode` is primitive processed at main processor level.

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX, the `\hisyntax` macro is integrated to the format, so you can write

```
\fontfam[lm]

\begtt \hisyntax{C}
void dfs(int p){
    if(o[p]) return;
    o[p]=1;
    c[p] = t++;
    for(int i=0; i<s[p].size(); ++i){
        dfs(s[p][i]);
    }
}

// -- --- `` '' `? `!
\endtt

\bye
```

and you get the same "colorized" result as in the previous answer.