# What's the easiest way to define an inline verbatim with |...| and display verbatim with ||...|| in plain TeX?

Tags: verbatim, plain-tex

I have been trying to define a verbatim environment in plain `TeX` with `|...|` for inline and `||...||` for display. Optimally, with an easy way to alter so that the visibility of spaces can be toggled (e.g. commenting out a line of code or using a different character like `*...*` and `**...**`).

I know that `tugboat.sty` defines this (see lines `1632-1963`), but it is a very long process and frankly quite hard to decipher. I was wondering what the easiest way to do this in plain `TeX` is.

I have also seen a few questions regarding verbatim in plain `TeX` (see [Define a special verbatim commmand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182870/define-a-special-verbatim-commmand) and [How to display code snippets in plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376245/how-to-display-code-snippets-in-plain-tex)), but these both use commands (e.g. `\verb{...}` and `\verbatim ...\endverbatim`).

This is for my own curiosity, as way to better understand `TeX`, and for use in my own plain `TeX` documents.

Comment: It's not like that the author of tugboat intentionally write it in a difficult way, so maybe tugboat.dtx have the documentation of that code for you to read...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is a short implementation if it's what you're after (probably not very robust).

```latex
\catcode`|=\active
\def|{\begingroup \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials \verbA}
\def\verbA#1{\ifx|#1\catcode`|=12 \expandafter\verblong \else \verbshort#1\fi}
\long\def\verbshort#1|{\tt#1\endgroup}
\edef\tmp{\long\def\noexpand\verblong##1\string|\string|}
    \tmp{$$\hbox{\tt#1}$$\endgroup}



lorem ipsum |{fjasdf&@(^#(%%| dolor ||\bye|\end|| \bye
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Couldn't you do `\tmp{\centerline{\tt#1}\endgroup}` instead of using math mode and `\hbox`?